# Update SQL Server logins for modified Active Directory users

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I have multiple MS SQL Servers with Windows authentication. In general administrative access is granted by active directory groups which works fine so far but we would like to alter our naming schema for those groups.
This is no problem at all, we can rename those groups (accountnames as well). Authentication still works as the login process looks up for the group SID. For better reading/cosmetic I would like to get all related loginnames on all SQL servers updated, since after having a look into sys.syslogins or Security/Logins, the old groupnames still persist (even after reboot). Is there a way to trigger MSSQL to update windows logins from the AD? Or do I have to script this on my own?